# How to transition group of foreign objects at different durations in D3

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, transition, opacity

I'm trying to transition opacities of a group of foreignObject text, specifically have them transition individually at different, random durations. Right now they all transition at the same time. Is that possible or do I have to make each one of them their own variables? Thank you for taking a look at this.

```
        var city = canvas.append('g')
                    .attr('width',1024)
                    .attr('text-anchor','start');

        city.append('foreignObject')
            .attr('x',40)
            .attr('y',0)
            .append('xhtml:body')
            .html("<h1>Milwaukee</h1><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>");

        city.append('foreignObject')
            .attr('x',365)
            .attr('y',0)
            .append('xhtml:body')
            .html("<h1>Chicago</h1><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>");

        city.append('foreignObject')
            .attr('x',690)
            .attr('y',0)
            .append('xhtml:body')
            .html("<h1>Detroit</h1><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>");
                    city.append('foreignObject')
            .attr('x',40)
            .attr('y',350)
            .append('xhtml:body')
            .html("<h1>Columbus</h1><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>");

        city.append('foreignObject')
            .attr('x',365)
            .attr('y',350)
            .append('xhtml:body')
            .html("<h1>Cleveland</h1><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>");

        city.append('foreignObject')
            .attr('x',690)
            .attr('y',350)
            .append('xhtml:body')
            .html("<h1>Louisville</h1><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>");


          city.transition()
            .duration((Math.random() * 500) + 100)
            .delay(0)
            .attr('opacity',0)
            .transition()
            .duration((Math.random() * 500) + 100)
            .delay(Math.random() * 500)
            .attr('opacity',1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, `city` is a single group. Thus, you're applying the opacity to that group only.

One solution is selecting all `foreignObjects` and using an `each`:

```
canvas.selectAll("foreignObject").each(function() {
    d3.select(this).transition()
        .duration((Math.random() * 1000) + 1000)
        .style('opacity', 0)
        .transition()
        .duration((Math.random() * 1000) + 100)
        .delay(Math.random() * 500)
        .style('opacity', 1);
})
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var canvas = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 800)
  .attr("height", 600)

var city = canvas.append('g');

city.append('foreignObject')
  .attr('x', 40)
  .attr('y', 0)
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 50)
  .style("opacity", 1)
  .append('xhtml:body')
  .html("<h1>Milwaukee</h1><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>");

city.append('foreignObject')
  .attr('x', 365)
  .attr('y', 0)
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 50)
  .style("opacity", 1)
  .append('xhtml:body')
  .html("<h1>Chicago</h1><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>");

city.append('foreignObject')
  .attr('x', 690)
  .attr('y', 0)
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 50)
  .style("opacity", 1)
  .append('xhtml:body')
  .html("<h1>Detroit</h1><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>");

city.append('foreignObject')
  .attr('x', 40)
  .attr('y', 350)
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 50)
  .style("opacity", 1)
  .append('xhtml:body')
  .html("<h1>Columbus</h1><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>");

city.append('foreignObject')
  .attr('x', 365)
  .attr('y', 350)
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 50)
  .style("opacity", 1)
  .append('xhtml:body')
  .html("<h1>Cleveland</h1><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>");

city.append('foreignObject')
  .attr('x', 690)
  .attr('y', 350)
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 50)
  .style("opacity", 1)
  .append('xhtml:body')
  .html("<h1>Louisville</h1><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>");

canvas.selectAll("foreignObject").each(function() {
  d3.select(this).transition()
    .duration((Math.random() * 1000) + 1000)
    .style('opacity', 0)
    .transition()
    .duration((Math.random() * 1000) + 100)
    .delay(Math.random() * 500)
    .style('opacity', 1);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

PS: You have to set the width and height of the `foreignObjects`.

PPS: There are some known bugs when changing the opacity of `foreignObjects` as you're doing right now. My answer here addresses **only your question**, not those bugs. The result, as you can see, has problems.

Comment: Thank you for your help! And I see what you're saying with the bugs in the foreignObjects. Good to know.